# ThemeColor doesn't exist in Microsoft Band 2 SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I'm following an example in the Microsoft Band SDK documentation to fill a button with a theme color but the code doesn't compile as Color and ThemeColor.BandBase do not exist in any packages. The code in the example is:

```
FilledPanel panel = new FilledPanel 
{ 
  Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102), 
  Color = ThemeColor.BandBase 
};
```

I'm assuming Color should be BackgroundColor as that property exists, but I can't find anything similar to ThemeColor that I can use. Does anyone know what I can use?

UPDATE: I think I may have solved it with this:

```
BandTheme theme = await bandClient.PersonalizationManager.GetThemeAsync();

// create a filled rectangle to provide the background for a button 
FilledPanel panel = new FilledPanel
{
  Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102,
  BackgroundColor = theme.Base
};
```

Yet to test. If it works will add as answer

Comment: workin for me.  thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method you've chosen should work.

You can also use the static accessor:

```
FilledPanel panel = new FilledPanel
{
  Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102,
  BackgroundColor = ThemeColor.BandBase
};
```

Comment: ThemeColor.BandBase was what wasn't working for me. Am I missing a declaration?

Comment: Yes sorry, just re-read your question. The MS documentation is *extremely* light on so I'd suggest if your current implementation works - go with it! MS API and docs will hopefully be updated and improved in near future.